# Proving divergence or convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{-n}{2n+5}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm really confused with this, you'll see why. I'm asked to determine if the sequence $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{-n}{2n+5}$ converges. So, to show it by the 'hard' way, we need to proove that the sequence is bounded and monotonic.

So first, we see that $\{a_n\}=\{-1/7,-2/9,-3/11,...\}$ where $\frac{-1}{7}>\frac{-2}{9}>\frac{-3}{11}$ and so on. So $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing. Now, we can find a lower bound $m$ such that $m\le a_n$, $\forall n\in N$:

$$m\le \frac{-n}{2n+5}$$

$$2n<2n+5$$
$$\frac{1}{2n+5}<\frac{1}{2n}$$
$$\implies \frac{-1}{2}<\frac{-n}{2n+5}$$
And so $\{a_n\}<\frac{-1}{2}$, $\forall n\in N$ is bounded sequence.

Left to proove is that $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic sequence. For that, we differentiate:

Let $f(x)=\frac{-x}{2x+5}, \forall x\ne\frac{-5}{2}$ where $f'(x)=\frac{-5}{(2x+5)^2}<0$, and so $f$ is strictly decreasing and for that, $\{a_n\}$ is monotone. With all that done, is enough ti conclude that the sequence converges, but $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{-n}{2n+5}=\frac{-1}{2}$ wich shows that $\{a_n\}$ diverges. I even try to use conditional convergence but there must be something I'm not getting yet. So is it non convergent?

Comment: $\sum a_n$ cannot converge if $a_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: So what's the point in the process above? Does it is okay?

Comment: You should say $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$ instead of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty$. Also, you should write "series" here.

Comment: +1 to your posting, for good effort, good work shown, making your posting a high quality posting.  The fact that you are confused about the subject matter, and that you therefore went off the rails is irrelevant to judging the quality of your posting.  With respect to your confusion about your posting, I agree with the answer of Sean Robertson.  Further, as your own analysis indicates, as $~n \to \infty,~$ the terms go toward $~(-1/2).~$  More concretely, for each $~n \geq 6,~$ the absolute value of each term is $~> (1/3).~$  ...see next comment

Comment: So, just examining the series from the 6th term on, you have a series that looks like $~-1 \times [ ~ |a_6| + |a_7| + |a_8| + \cdots~], ~$ where for each $~n \geq 6, ~ |a_n| > (1/3).$

Comment: Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do all of the work to show monotone and bounded. If $a_n \not \to 0$ then $\sum a_n$ is divergent, full stop.

You also seem to be confusing the conditions for convergent **sequence** versus a convergent **series**. Just because the sequence is convergent does not mean the corresponding sum converges - the canonical counterexample is $b_n = \frac{1}{n}.$ Indeed, $b_n \to 0$ but $\sum b_n = \infty$. However - every monotone and bounded sequence is convergent - this is easy to prove. But it doesn't mean it is summable!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answered helped, please accept it by clicking the check.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ be a rational function, with $p,q$ polynomials. Then it follows directly from the Limit Comparison Test that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g(n)$ is convergent if and only if $\deg p\le \deg q+2$.